# Precision of fast moving clocks to measure unidirectional speed of light

Tags: visible-light

In reading the following Wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ives%E2%80%93Stilwell_experiment#Fast_moving_clocks

Do they mean that the precision of the measurement is around $2 \times 10^{-8} c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If special relativity is valid,  α has to be 0.

You can see it by opening the link here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.7951.pdf

> The lasers’ Doppler shifted frequencies
>   required for resonance are measured with an accuracy of < 4×10−9 using optical-optical double resonance spectroscopy.  This allows us to verify the Special Relativity relation between the time dilation factor γ and the velocity β,γ√(1−β^2)= 1 to within±2.3×10−9
>   at this velocity.

So yes, you are right, the measurements give you an accuracy of this 2.3×10−9.